# Unity 5.6 : Unit test does not appear in "TestRunner">"Play Mode"

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine

When I write a unit test, it properly appears in "TestRunner">"EditMode", but not in "TestRunner">"PlayMode". I have enabled the playmode, but it seems to not recognize my script.

- the script is in a folder named "Editor"
- the script can be run into the "EditMode", resulting in "EditMode test can only yield null" (which makes sense as this script calls "WaitForFixedUpdate()")

I tried to do it in a new project, resulting in the same situation : unit tests cannot be run in Play Mode.

This is basic unit test code from unity doc : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SeNOAVYaq9HUjsKAC2ZvRwKLD2MCNyV4LwcsP3BXm0s/edit

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator GameObject_WithRigidBody_WillBeAffectedByPhysics()
{
    var go = new GameObject();
    go.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    var originalPosition = go.transform.position.y;
    
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    Assert.AreNotEqual(originalPosition, go.transform.position.y);
}
```

Unity version : 5.6.0f3

Did anyone met this problem before?
Did I missed a step into Unit Test creation?

Thanks

Comment: _"the script is in a folder named "Editor""_ Are you sure it should be there? All files inside of `Editor` folder are not referenced in your game, thus making it not available in the playmode ( the game ).

Comment: solved the problem ! Thanks, I did not mind about that.